# Spring Security Access Checks and Context-Based Authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring's expression-based authorization check system to configure that certain checks pass before a user is able to access certain paths of my API:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/objA/{id}/**")
      .access("@objAChecker.checkAccess(authentication.principal, #id)")
    .antMatchers("/api/objB/{id}/**")
      .access("@objBChecker.checkAccess(authentication.principal, #id)");
}
```

Where `objAChecker` and `objBChecker` both have a `checkAccess` method that returns a boolean true only if the user may access the given object.

However, I would like to configure my security such that if a user is trying to access the objA, the security context's Authentication is updated to a new one that contains information relevant to objA, including a set of granted authorities that's only valid in the context of the objA that the user is requesting. That way, in my controller and service layer, I can take advantage of method-level `@PreAuthorize` annotations, using a set of granted authorities that's essentially "context-aware", because they'd be derived from the user and their relationship to the objA they're accessing.

My naive approach to this would be as follows:

1. In `objAChecker.checkAccess`, after fetching the objA, if user may access it, use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication` to update the security context's authentication to one whose granted authorities are specific to the objA and user that's accessing it.
2. On a controller method, for example `@GetMapping("/api/objA/{id}/data")`, I would be able to place `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('read_data')")`, so that only users who have the `read_data` authority for the specific objA they're requesting can have access.

My question, then, is as follows: **Is the above solution a valid way to achieve context-based granted authorities in Spring?** Furthermore, is there a simpler approach built into spring security for solving this sort of problem that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You may be able to use [`@PreFilter` or `@PostFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/authorization.html#filtering-using-prefilter-and-postfilter) or [`PermissionEvaluator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/authorization.html#el-permission-evaluator) for this.

Comment: @dan1st I would like to avoid additional annotations that would need to be applied to controller/service methods alongside the standard `@PreAuthorize`, so that in the rest of the application, no special attention needs to be made to the fact that the user's granted authorities are dependent on the context of the request.

Comment: If that doesn't suffice, you could also try using [ACLs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/authorization.html#domain-acls). - From the [Key Concepts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/authorization.html#domain-acls-key-concepts) section: "A way of ensuring a given principal is permitted to work with your objects (or something they return), after methods are called"

Comment: Yes, I just read through the documentation you provided, but I don't think that ACLs are an acceptable solution to this use case, because I do need more fine-grained permissions than simply read/write/create/delete, and it would require an entire separate ACL table structure which makes it difficult or impossible to have "derived" permissions that are based on a user's relationship to a parent or child of an objA, for example. I will try to make an implementation of my proposed solution to see how practical that is.